# Regex to validate cookie string (Key value paired)

Tags: regex, cookies

So far I tried this regex but no luck.

```
([^=;]+=[^=;]+(;(?!$)|$))+
```

**Valid Strings:**

```
something=value1;another=value2



something=value1 ; anothe=value2
```

**Invalid Strings:**

```
something=value1 ;;;name=test

some=value=3;key=val

somekey=somevalue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use an optional repeating group to get the matches.

If you don't want to cross newline boundaries, you might add `\n` or `\r\n` to the negated character class.

```
^[^=;\n]+=[^=;\n]+(?:;[^=;\n]+=[^=;\n]+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^=;\n]+=[^=;\n]+` Match the key and value using a negated character class
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `;[^=;\n]+=[^=;\n]+` Match a comma followed by the same pattern
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZqCPa/1)